# Encode a sequence of numbers as a single number -- use chinese remainder theorem

Tags: algorithm, chinese-remainder-theorem

I need to encode a sequence `S` of an arbitrary number of elements (but finite) with an whole number `K`, and be able to decode `K` in order to obtain back the initial sequence.

I need to do it such that a computer be able to cope good with the number `K`.

I did it so (in lisp):

- suppose that the sequence S has n elements e1, ... en
- generate first n prime numbers p1 ... pn
- write K = p1^e1 + p2 ^ e2 + ... + pn ^ en

I tried this method. However, I get huge numbers.

I know that it is possible to use the `chinese remainder theorem` to solve the problem, and the `K` obtained so is not that large.

Somebody can help me to use this theorem such that I encode a sequence ?

EDIT:

I wish to see the algorithm of encoding using `ch r th` using a concrete simple example. I cannot understand the theoretical ideas from wikipedia and other web resources.

Comment: We're not going to do your work for you.  Show us what you've tried so far, and where you're stuck.

Comment: I do not need to do work. I need somebody to explain me the logic of the algorithm how to encode this, exactly in the same way I explained how I did, using a sequence of prime numbers. In my case, the generated number K is too great, so the method has not practical use.

Comment: I heard that one can use the chinese remainder th. to encode the sequence, and I wish somebody to explain me the idea. This is what I ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [Gödel numbering of sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering_for_sequences).  This is a way of encoding a (finite) sequence of numbers as a single number.  The Chinese Remainder Theorem gives a recursive method of construction.

Comment: Can you describe concretely the algorithm , because I cannot understand the theory from Wikipedia and similar articles ?